# When detecting a keyboard key is released. What happened if the key is released at the end of the game loop?

Tags: sfml, events, keyboard

When detecting a keyboard key is released. What happened if the key is released at the end of the game loop, how could the pollEvent function, which is at the top of the game loop, and it is a brand new call of the function every iteration of the game loop, detect that key released at the end of the game loop in the last frame?

```
while (window.isOpen())
{
    /*
    ****************************************
    Handle the player input
    ****************************************
    */ 
    Event event;
    while (window.pollEvent(event))
    {
      if (event.type == Event::KeyReleased && !paused)
      {
          // Some code here
      }
    }
    ...
    /*
    ****************************************
    Update the scene
    ****************************************
    *
    ...  
    /*
    ****************************************
    Draw the scene
    ****************************************
    *        
    // a finger released from a key here!!! 
    // The next loop will reset all the entire event types, I think
}
```

Comment: Why do you think the loop will reset all event types - which line of code makes it do that? You did not call `window.resetAllEventTypes();` at the end of the loop, and the `}` has nothing to do with anything

Comment: Because I think a new SFML's event queue will be newly initialized every iteration of the loop and each time an iteration of the loop ends, it will be destroyed.

Comment: Which line of code do you think newly initializes a new SFML's event queue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The System events will be placed in SFML's event queue and be processed during the next loop. Imagine if the events were lost? What a bad game dev library that would make!

*Roughly*, the way a program works on Windows is like this:

1. System events are queued by the OS into a queue for the program
2. At some point the program tells the OS it's ready to receive the OS events queued for it; this is done through a set of special functions
3. The program reacts to each event in the way it sees fit
4. The program tells the OS that they're done with handling the queue
5. The OS does its thing and queues more System events for the the program (loop back to 1.)

When you start an SFML app, it does essentially the same thing. When it receives OS events, it queues them until you're ready to process them. Once you process them, and when the SFML event queue is empty, you update your game logic, you render and then you start again.

No System events are lost.